# Objective c: How to store indices forming a sequence from middle to middle (indices for array or vector)

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, indices

I have an array of structs, these structs are basically two points forming an edge. I use structs because of performance.

Now i have object A holding the edges and a method in this object to tell another object B about a list of consecutive of edges in this edges-array.

Edges:

```
e0 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7
```

Possible edges to return:

```
e0 e1 e2
e6 e7 e0 e1 e2
```

How would you return the info about the list of edges? They have to be ordered as shown. My problem is the case when the range starts near the end. Otherwise i could just use NSIndexSet. Using arrays seems not to be a good idea in this case because of performance. There will be many points and edges and things with points and edges.

Comment: Your possible ranges to return are just a list of edges. I see no ranges.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am searching for a efficient way to return those edges/ the indices of those edges. I will change the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a set of consecutive "wrapping-around" indices as three numbers:

- total number of indices in the original array,
- first index of the index set,
- number of indices in the index set.

That would be `(8, 0, 3)` for your first example `e0 e1 e2`, and
`(8, 6, 5)` for your second example `e6 e7 e0 e1 e2`.

Comment: I don't get how i can use NSIndexSet to be honest. The indices are sorted so how could they be usefull? 
Second approach is usefull, i could probably also use a simple struct with those 3 values. This leads me to another question, i will have to iterate over those indices (obviously), so i would need a check in each loop of my for(.. to check if i reached the end of the array (example e6 e7 e0 e1 e2). Right? I wonder what would be faster, this solution or the solution from Avt.

Comment: @user3477549: You are right, NSIndexSet was problably not the best idea, I have removed that part of the answer. - You are also right about the iterating. Checking for the end of the array should be very fast (it is just an integer comparison), and you don't need to allocate memory. But I did not compare it. You should choose what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

"Possible edges to return: e0 e1 e2 e6 e7 e0 e1 e2 ... They have to be ordered as shown"

If you need to save order and to save some elements twice (e0, e1, e2) you can not use NSIndexSet.

[NSIndexSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> You should not use index sets to store an arbitrary collection of
>   integer values because index sets store indexes as sorted ranges. This
>   makes them more efficient than storing a collection of individual
>   integers. It also means that each index value can only appear once in
>   the index set.

Since Objective C is build over C you can use C-style arrays. It will be very fast.

Small sample:

```
int* getIndexes(int *number)
{
    // here we will generate a fake array;
    *number = 10;
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)*(*number));
    for (int i = 0; i < (*number); i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    return a;
}
```

This function should be used the following way

```
int N;
int *indexes = getIndexes(&N);
// now in N we have count of indexes
// ... process indexes here
free(indexes)
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a much better solution than what i came up with. I even tried storing NSValues in NSArray but that is a huge overhead. I guess it will be faster than emptiing an NSMutableArray and filling it with NSValues at each computation?

Comment: Sure. It will be much more faster.